# How to Toggle (Hide/Show) an Element in JavaScript

Tags: html, function, button, show-hide

I have an invoice webapp and trying to add a button to Toggle (Hide/Show) invoice stamp before printing/saving pdf
but I can't make it work.

Stamp part : source from ".json" template file

```php
<?php
    $etat_footer .= "<div class=\"col-xs-4\">";
    if( trim($signature_stamp) != "" ){
      $etat_footer .= "<p style=\"text-align: center; border-bottom: 0px solid #666;\">
        <img src=\"".($signature_stamp)."\" style=\"max-width:1px; max-height:160px; margin-bottom:-1px;\" />
      </p>";
      ?>
      <?php
      
    }else{
      $etat_footer .= "<p>&nbsp;</p><p style=\"border-bottom: 0px solid #666;\">&nbsp;</p>";
    }
    $etat_footer .= "<p class='text-md-center'>".$signature_txt."</p>
    </div>";
  }else{
    $etat_footer .= "<div class=\"col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-8\">";
    
      $etat_footer .= "<p style=\"text-align: center; border-bottom: 0px solid #666;\">
        <img src=\"".($signature_stamp)."\" style=\"max-width:170px; max-height:160px; margin-bottom:-1px;\" />
      </p>";
    
    $etat_footer .= "<p class='text-md-center'>".$signature_txt."</p>
    </div>";
  }
}
?>
```

I tried creating a button with the function to hide the element but did not work:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Hide/Show Stamp</button>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementByClassName("col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-8");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure `getElementByClassName()`  exists?

Comment: This is not related to `PHP`

Comment: _What_ doesn't work? Blank page? Wrong element shown/hidden? Any errors in your browser's DevConsole?

Comment: @brombeer Nothing Happen when I click on the button.

Comment: Nothing in your browser's DevConsole? `getElementByClassName` is a typo, it's `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two notes:

- probably you want to use getElementsByClassName, since getElementByClassName by default is not decelerated.
- in case you use getElementsByClassName, don't forget to select result element

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Working example bellow:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-8");
  if (x[0].style.display === "none") {
    x[0].style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x[0].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-8">
STAMP
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Hide/Show Stamp</button>
```

Comment: @Dj8lacko this has helped you ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but in my case I want to hide this part " $etat_footer .= "<div class=\"col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-8\">";" and in your working example you made a new div with the same class name" do you have any idea how I can make mine work ? because I tried it not working.

Comment: Fix your JS code like I did (getElementByClassName to getElementsByClassName and x to x[0] 3x times) and it should work with a note that you have only one div at page with this classes. In my example I went away from php code since it result will be HTML code I used - just for POC.
Plus as suggested others, you need to figure out with console, in case there is no errors, even you make error deliberately - probably console is configured with wrong filter settings.

Comment: Hi @Romualds Thank you so much for keeping up with me, it finally worked, it turned out that the output result of the class name is " etat_footer" an,d not"col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-8" so I changed that on JS and it did the trick. Thanks again.